# Jquery click event causing loop to execute only one time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show next five divs each time when i click show more button, 5 divs will be shown default when load, here is my code,

```
var counterBox = 5;
$("#show_more_location").click(function() {
    $(".loading-container").show();
    for (var inc = 5; inc <= 5; inc++) {
        if(counterBox<50){
            counterBox = counterBox + 1;
            $(".location-box:nth-child("+counterBox+")").slideDown().addClass("show_box").delay(100);
        }  
    }
    $(".loading-container").delay(5000).hide();         
});
```

Problem is that when I click show more button, it loops only once, and stops. Only one div is showing ,I want to show 5 divs on show buttonclick.

Can anyonehelp?

Comment: If your loop counter starts with the value 5, then don’t expect it to be lesser than or equal 5 after you _added_ a positive value to 5 ...

Comment: The risks of copy pasting a var decleration...

Comment: thnx @CBroe, its because of lot of work, just initialize inc = 0, it works fine, thnx again

Comment: @MuhammadAkberKhan Then you should accept OddBrew's answer.

Comment: and one more thing is loading div is not showing/hide, its executing very fast, i have also add delay of 5 sec but loading is not showing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you init your `inc` iterator with `5`, and get out of the loop when it's higher than `5`:

```
for (var inc = 5; inc <= 5; inc++) {
   ...
}
```

Try initializing it with `1`:

```
for (var inc = 1; inc <= 5; inc++) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: but one more point can you help, loading div is not showing, as i have also add the delay in hide, check my question, i have update

Comment: @MuhammadAkberKhan did you try with the function `setTimeOut()` instead ? Check out its usage here https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `inc` in the for loop to 5, then checking if it is lower than or is 5. So it runs once. Make `inc` 0 to run it 6 times.